# Why does the non synchronized method get called while acquiring the lock on object?

Tags: java, multithreading

Iam new to syncronization and multithreading please answer why this code is not getting a lock on object b.

```
public class Tetsclass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B();
        A a = new A(b);
        A2 a2 = new A2(b);
        Thread t1= new Thread(a);
        Thread t2= new Thread(a2);
        t1.start();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        t2.start();
    }
}
class B {
    public synchronized void waitfor() {        
        synchronized (B.class) {
            System.out.println("Lock aquired  on "+System.currentTimeMillis());
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {      
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Lock released");
        }

    }
    public void readObject() {
        System.out.println("readobject by thread==="+Thread.currentThread().getName()+" on "+System.currentTimeMillis());

    }
}
class A2 implements Runnable {

    B b=null;
    public A2(B b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {     
        b.readObject();     
    }
}
class A implements Runnable {

    B b=null;
    public A(B b) {
        this.b = b;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {             
        b.waitfor();                
    }
}
```

I expected the output :

```
Lock aquired  on 1380016080337
Lock released
readobject by thread===Thread-1 on 1380016082337
```

but the output is :

```
Lock aquired  on 1380016080337
readobject by thread===Thread-1 on 1380016082337
Lock released
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `readObject` method, including its invocation from `A2#run`, involves no lock acquisition. Therefore the lock your other thread is holding is inconsequential to the progress of  the execution of `readObject`.

Apparently you have a misunderstanding of the semantics of locks. You believe that when you lock `B.class`, you have locked "the whole class". The state of matters is quite different: `B.class` is just another object, and all objects have their associated monitor, which can be acquired by a thread. Mutual exclusion happens only between threads which contend to acquire  *one and the same lock*. There is no semantic relationship between an object as a lock and any of its methods, and the same stands for class objects vz. instances of that class.

One way your misunderstanding may have arisen is via the objects used implicitly on `synchronized` methods: a synchronized instance method acquires its `this` as a lock, while a synchronized static method acquires a lock on its associated class object.

Comment: yes but while calling the syncronized method it will acquire the lock on whole object . So why this readObject is being called?

Comment: Are you sure you have read my answer in its entirety? Your above question is answered in detail in my second and third paragraph.

Answer (score 2):

Its behaving as expected.
Here is what happens on the time line

`a` - calls wait (which sleeps 5 secs before releasing lock)
`a2` - calls read which prints read message.

```
          t          t+dt                                                 t+dt+5
 ---------|-----------|--------------------------------|--------------------------|----------
      [a starts] [print(lock acquired)]             [sleeps(5)]           [print(lock released)]
                            t+2
 ----------------------------|--------------|--------------------------|--------------
                         [a2 starts]   [print(read message)]
```

There is no locking of any kind in your `readObject()`

Answer (score 0):

Since the `readObject()` doesn't require to acquire a lock, it won't wait for the other thread to release the lock. This confusion might have come because of the `Thread.sleep(2000)` you've in your test class.

Try to change that to `Thread.sleep(10000)` and see the output. You'll get your desired result.

In the first case, the `A2` thread will wait for **2 secs** after `A` starts, and will execute without any further delay whereas your `A` is held up for **5 secs** when it acquired the lock.

In the second case, the `A2` thread will wait for **10 secs** after `A` starts, and within those **10 secs**, your `A` will start, sleep for **5 secs** and release the lock, after which your `A2` will be executed without any delays.

Answer (score 0):

Class B object can be synchronized to get the output as expected. There is no synchronization is involve in current code execution.  To synchronized this code and get the expected output, we can modify Class B as

```
class B {
    public synchronized void waitfor() {        
        synchronized (B.class) {
            System.out.println("Lock aquired  on "+System.currentTimeMillis());
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {      
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Lock released");
        }

    }
    public void readObject() {
        synchronized(B.class)
        {
        System.out.println("readobject by thread==="+Thread.currentThread().getName()+" on "+System.currentTimeMillis());
        }
    }
}
```